# Getting error on page which is removed from project

Tags: angular, tinymce

I tried to used tiny MCE editor in my angular project and first time it works perfectly but after that it was giving me error like theme path not found etc. Then I did some changes according to the documentation and it works, but after that again it was giving me an strange error that editor component not found on my component html where tiny MCE was used[image]. So I planned to use some other editor and removed the line from html code but still I was getting the same error even the line is commented.
Now I have removed the component from my project but getting same error even the component does not exist in project.

**What I have tried**
Uninstalled all node modules and installed again
, Clean cache
but still no luck.

Please help

Comment: Just stop your project. Close the VS Code editor and Serve your app again

Comment: Tried this almost 50 times. Also restarted my system but no luck

Comment: I think you are still using <editor> component, search '<editor' in project  and delete it.